# Custom MVC4 Authorization Role Management

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, security

I'm trying to create custom Roles for my MVC4 project. But I have found that there's little about it. I have found [this example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7) . But are there any other way of defined my own  Authorization Roles. Because I liked to get the User Roles from a database instead of the IIS.

Comment: Take a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449499/mvc-4-intranet-authentication-with-custom-roles/14466907#14466907

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed a [MembershipProvider](http://kitsula.com/Article/Custom-Membership-Provider-for-MVC)  and a [RoleProvider](http://kitsula.com/Article/Custom-Role-Provider-for-MVC). Also, I needed to add an extra value to my [SetAuthCookie](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-cs).