# ASP.NET MVC Intranet Application. Roles Based Authentication linked to Users Table in application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I am at the beginning of writing an ASP.NET MVC application that will use Active Directory authentication.

I don't want the users to have to log in I want the ability to authenticate the user from their domain credentials and assign them roles.

I want to be able to assign roles to AD Users and AD groups using some kind of Admin views.

Are there any resources that deal with this?

Most importantly I want to be able to link the domain credentials with a User table in my application (it is essentially a Helpdesk Ticket application). How can I successfully link a user in my application DB to a Windows Authenticated account?

Thanks

Please ask for clarification if this does not make sense.

[MVC 4 Intranet Authentication with Custom Roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449499/mvc-4-intranet-authentication-with-custom-roles)

This seems to be a good resource, but any advice would be great

Comment: you can select `Windows Authentication` when creating the project, it'll handle about all of that for you

Comment: @Jonesy 
How do I link an AD account to a users table in my admin area?
How do I create and manage roles using this method?
All that it seems to do by default is allow you to display a username

Comment: @ASPNETMVC-Newbie: roles are created in AD and users are assigned to roles in AD. Linking to custom tables is possible with `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` which gives you the name of authenticated user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Authentication will verify the user exists on the AD, if you want to verify they exist in your user table, you can use a CustomAttribute (I'm using the EntityFramework):

```
public class AuthorizeDB : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    ProjectDB db = new ProjectDB();

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            return false;

        var name = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        return db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == name) != null;
    }
}
```

and decorate your classes with `[AuthorizeDB]` or set it for the entire application.  The `User.Identity.Name` will come in as `Domain\Username`

If you're using custom Roles within your application, it should be about the same as any other type of authentication.  Link a user with a role and then validate the roles they are in.