# Custom error page for failed windows authentication in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication, custom-error-pages

According to [How to use custom Errors page in Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348668/how-to-use-custom-errors-page-in-windows-authentication) (although never marked as an answer), you have to add an IIS HTTP error handler to "catch" failed windows authentications and serve up a custom error page.

However, 403 is never reached, failed WinAuth ends with 401 Unauthorized. However, if I add an IIS HTTP error handler for 401, the NTLM authentication process does not work anymore (uses 401 internally as well).

Anybody has a working solution for a custom error page (not static, I want to execute an MVC controller action!) when windows authentication failed?

Answer (score 0):

The code below isn't exactly what you need, but this is how I am handling unhandled Exceptions. You could alter this to route differently based on status code or exception type. (This is from Global.asax)

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
                Server.ClearError();

                var routeData = new RouteData();
                routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Global");
                int status = 0;

                if (ex.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
                {
                    var httpException = (HttpException)ex;
                    var code = httpException.GetHttpCode();
                    status = code;
                }
                else
                {
                    status = 500;
                }

                //Create a new error based off the exception and the error status.
                NameSpace.Models.ErrorModel Error = new ErrorModel(status, ex);
                string innerException = "";
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    innerException = "\n Inner Ex: " + ex.InnerException.StackTrace;
                }

                log.Error("Error Id: " + Error.ErrorId + " Error: " + ex.Message + ". Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace + innerException);
                routeData.Values.Add("error", Error);

                IController errorController = new NameSpace.Controllers.ErrorController();
                errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));


            }
```

Update: Apologies, I did not read your post completely. If you were to perform LDAP authentication within your application you could leverage the above code to catch and handle the error with a controller. Unfortunately, I cannot provide direct guidance on your issue above.

Comment: Are you sure the ASP.NET pipeline is called for win auth errors? Can't observe that behavior...